# How can I have multi-level categorized unit tests in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have a project, which has a lot of unit tests.

It has several sub projects, and I'd rather use better categorization system.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with NUnit Adpaper.

And I can categorize unit tests based on Project, Class or [Category] attribute which is placed on top of them:

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("MyCategory")]
    public class SomeTests
    {
        [TestCase(2, 2, ExpectedResult = 4)]
        public Int32 Test2(Int32 firstNumber, Int32 secondNumber)
        {
            return firstNumber + secondNumber;
        }
    }
```

So, how can I categorize them as following?

```
Category1
     SubCategory1
          UnitTest2
          UnitTest1
     SubCategory2
          UnitTest2
          UnitTest1
Category2
     SubCategory1
          UnitTest2
          UnitTest1
```

Is there any attribute as like as Category attribute that perform categorization much better? or any other config somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I think there is no *nice* solution for this. In the end I came up with "namespacing" my categories. For example:

```
Category1
Category1.SubCategory1
Category1.SubCategory1.UnitTest2
Category1.SubCategory1.UnitTest1
Category1.SubCategory2
Category1.SubCategory1.UnitTest2
Category1.SubCategory1.UnitTest1
Category2
Category2.SubCategory1
Category2.SubCategory1.UnitTest2
Category2.SubCategory1.UnitTest1
```

As NUnit v3 is currently in active development you could [propose this as a feature request](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-framework/issues).